# Classify, upto isomorphism, all groups of order 24 which are the quotient group of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, abelian-groups

Classify, upto isomorphism, all groups of order 24 which are the quotient group of $\mathbb{Z}^2$.

I know that the abelian group of order 24 are

$\mathbb{Z}_{24}$,

$\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$,

$\mathbb{Z}_{4}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{8}\times\mathbb{Z}_{3}$

$\mathbb{Z}_{12}\times\mathbb{Z}_{2}$.

I tried to apply the Fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups. Can anyone suggest me how do I apply this theorem on question?

Comment: $\Bbb Z_4\times\Bbb Z_2\times\Bbb Z_3$ and $\Bbb Z_{12}\times\Bbb Z_2$  look isomorphic to me.

Comment: Ditto for $\mathbb Z_8\times\mathbb Z_3$ and $\mathbb Z_{24}$.

Answer (score 2):

The quotients should have one or two generators. In the first case it is the cyclic group with 24 elements. In the second case, by the Fundamental Theorem, it is the direct product of two cyclic groups. The product of their orders should be 24, so we have one of these options: $C_2\times C_{12}$, $C_3\times C_8$ (it is $C_{24}$, so this case has been considered), or  $C_4\times C_6$ (which is the same as $C_4\times C_2\times C_3= C_2\times C_{12}$).